# Potential due to infinite plate carrying a finite charge

Tags: electrostatics, charge

I've solved many problems where something is grounded and you've to figure out the charge distribution. The general strategy is to set the potential of the grounded thing equal to zero and solve.

However what i'm curious about is  how do you calculate potential due to a finite charge carrying plate (which we generally approximate as being infinite) ? Also , how do you calculate potential of the plate due to itself?

Basically how do you approach a problem like this -
[image] 
Net initial charges are A and B.
One can figure out the distribution of charges as shown using the fact that there is no field in conducting plate and gauss's law. But what happens when the plate on right is grounded?

I searched this on the internet as well as many books but could not find anything related. The closest thing I came across was "The image method" but I don't think it can be applied here (since it concerns a point charge along with a single plate).

Comment: I don't understand: if the plate on the left is neutral, how can it be than on some side the charge is $(A+B)/2$ and on the other, $(A-B)/2$?

Comment: @Sofia It is not neutral , it has a charge A while the right plate has charge B. I've written it in the image : "Net initial charges are A and B" I've now written it in the post also.

Comment: Why do you think that the charge on the plate on the left should be $(A+B)/2$ on the external side? Why shouldn't all the charge A go to the internal side? Also, why should a charge $(A+B)/2$ remain on the side of the plate on the right connected to the ground? Why shouldn't this side be neutral?

Comment: @Sofia The situation shown in the figure is before grounding. I want to know what happens after grounding.

Comment: @Sofia By the way , does it matter that i ground the left surface of plate or right surface of plate? ( I'm guessing it doesn't)

Comment: isn't the surface of a metal an equipotential surface? Isn't the surface of the plate on the left an equipotential surface?

Comment: @Sofia Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21375/discussion-between-a-googler-and-sofia).